# How does this function to swap array elements work?

Tags: javascript, swap, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

I saw this function on here that will swap two array elements but I can't seem to figure out how it works. It looks like there is some sort of array destructuring going on (?). I just don't understand how and why the original `data`-array is actually changed.

Can someone please explain to me how this works?

```js
const swap = (a, i, j) => {
  [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]]  // ???
}

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

swap(data, 0, 2)

console.log(data)
```

Comment: The array is passed by reference. So technically you modify the original array.

Comment: Super interesting.  Never would have thought to use deconstruction in that manner.  It's like when your brain realizes you could use `[a,b].includes(c)` to shorthand or statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the righthand side:

```
[a[j], a[i]]
```

This creates a new array with two elements: the element at index `j`, followed by the element at index `i`.

On the left hand side it's doing destructuring

```
[a[i], a[j]] =
```

So that's the equivalent of the following:

```
a[i] = theNewArray[0];
a[j] = theNewArray[1];
```

Since this is mutating `a`, those changes can be felt by any references to the array, so `data` will "see" the changes.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up perfectly. I didn't realize that it is also possible to destructure into existing object/array properties.